# Rviz displays camera image incorrectly after changing gazebo sensor resolution

Tags: rviz, camera, gazebo-ignition

I simulate a camera:

```
  <gazebo reference="${name}_rgb_camera_frame">
      <sensor name="rgbd_camera" type="rgbd_camera">
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <topic>/rgbd_camera</topic>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.25</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>320</width>
            <height>240</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.3</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
          <optical_frame_id>${name}_rgb_camera_optical_frame</optical_frame_id>
        </camera>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
      </sensor>
      <xacro:material_darkgray />
    </gazebo>
```

And it works as expected. On this image, you can see the rviz output together with parts of the robot, that you can use for reference. Image:
[image]
When I change the parameters to:

```
   <width>1920</width>
   <height>1080</height>
```

The camera image is incorrect:
[image]
It looks like it didn't shift the center of the image, and instead just "extended its size".

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that camera_info does not update the data about the lens of the camera when you change image resolution. Specifically principal point (p_cx, p_cy). See this docs: https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html

The fix is to overwrite it manually. Just add this under  tag:

```
       <lens>
          <projection>
            <p_cx>960</p_cx>
            <p_cy>540</p_cy>
          </projection>
        </lens>
```

Values for p_cx and p_cy are respectively half of your resolution width and height.

The working sensor description looks like this (unless I find any other issues):

```
 <gazebo reference="realsense_rgb_camera_frame">
    <sensor name="rgbd_camera" type="rgbd_camera">
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <topic>/rgbd_camera</topic>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.25</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.3</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <lens>
          <projection>
            <p_cx>960</p_cx>
            <p_cy>540</p_cy>
          </projection>
        </lens>
        <optical_frame_id>realsense_rgb_camera_optical_frame</optical_frame_id>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <xacro:material_darkgray />
  </gazebo>
```

Cheers!